# Android BSSID based proximity alert

Tags: android, wifi

I would like my android application to react when the phone enters in a particular building or in a particular area. I could use normal proximity alerts, but i was wondering if it could be possible to periodically check for a specific BSSID in the mobile phone range (for example every 30 seconds, to keep it responsive enough).

Is it a good idea? Or maybe just normal proximity alert would be enough? Is this already implemented somewhere?

I'm mainly worried about battery consumption and responsiveness.
Hope it's clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have an app that uses BSSID based functionality so it is possible. You can create a BroadcastReceiver for WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION. Battery consumption is a big problem because this receiver will be invoked more than you want it to.

Your best bet is creating a long running background service that periodically registers the broadcast receiver, (optionally) calls WifiManager.scan (because data will likely be coming in anyway) and then unregisters itself.

You might consider 60 or 90 seconds to be good enough and it would be much better on the battery.

Take a look at the app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.heleron.wifiroamingfix I would say it is an example of a battery hog.

Also consider that the higher level location functionality of the SDK takes advantage of wifi and might be more suited for your type of app. Searching for bssids is a wifi specific solution which is fine if your problem relates specifically to wifi.